# Python thread timer, not executing or executing instantly

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I am trying to implement a threaded timer to control a timeout for a serial process.

```
def tst_setMaxTimeFlag():

    lock.acquire()
    maxTimeFlag = 1
    lock.release()

    print "timeout!"
    return

def tst_setMaxTimeTimer(maxResponseTime):
    global responseTimer

    lock.acquire()
    maxTimeFlag = 0
    lock.release()

    responseTimer = threading.Timer(2,tst_setMaxTimeFlag)
    print "timer set!"
    responseTimer.start        
    print "timer start!"
    return
```

I would imagine the output to be:

1. timer set
2. timer start
3. timeout!

However, the tst_setMaxTimeFlag() is never called and timeout! is never printed.

If I alter `responseTimer = threading.Timer(2,tst_setMaxTimeFlag)` to `responseTimer = threading.Timer(2,tst_setMaxTimeFlag())` the timeout function is called immediately regardless of the time parameter.

maxTimeFlag is set as a global in main and initialized to 0.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lost all the indentation in your code snippet, so it's hard to be sure what you did.

The most obvious problem is `responseTimer.start`.  That merely retrieves the `start` method of your `responseTimer` object.  You need to **call** that method to start the timer; i.e., do `responseTimer.start()`.

Then it will produce the output you expected, with a delay of about 2 seconds before the final "timeout!" is printed.